# How do I get a sysprepped/generalized instance of WinServer2008R2 International to start without user interaction?

Tags: windows, azure, windows-server-2008-r2

We are trying to get a Windows Server 2008R2 image onto Azure, but we are having trouble because it is an international version of Windows.  For this to work, the instance must start on Hyper-V without any user interaction.

Without an unattend.xml file, on first boot, this version of Windows asks for the language and to accept the EULA.  The Azure provisioning process can't handle this, so the provisioning times out.

We are attempting to construct an unattend.xml file to resolve this.

We have succeeded in getting rid of the language page, but we have not been able to get rid of the EULA page.  When we attempt to do so using the attached unattend.xml file, the VM will boot on Hyper-V, but open a command prompt window titled "Administrator: ERROR HANDLER", indicating the unattend.xml file is bad.

Our unattend.xml file is below.  When we add the Userdata and OOBE sections, that causes the error.  When we leave them out, we get the accept EULA screen that we can't have when provisioning a Windows VM on Azure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="windowsPE">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SetupUILanguage>
                <UILanguage>en-us</UILanguage>
            </SetupUILanguage>
            <InputLocale>en-us</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>en-us</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguage>en-us</UILanguage>
            <UILanguageFallback>en-us</UILanguageFallback>
            <UserLocale>en-us</UserLocale>
            <UserData>
                <AcceptEula>true</AcceptEula>
                <FullName>Authorized User</FullName>
                <Organization>PTC</Organization>
                <ProductKey>
                    <Key>xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx</Key>
                    <WillShowUI>Never</WillShowUI>
                </ProductKey>
            </UserData>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <InputLocale>en-us</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>en-us</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguage>en-us</UILanguage>
            <UILanguageFallback>en-us</UILanguageFallback>
            <UserLocale>en-us</UserLocale>
            <OOBE>
                <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
            </OOBE>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="specialize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <InputLocale>en-us</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>en-us</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguage>en-us</UILanguage>
            <UILanguageFallback>en-us</UILanguageFallback>
            <UserLocale>en-us</UserLocale>
        </component>
    </settings>
</unattend>
```

Comment: This seems like a really good problem description. Can I suggest including a question somewhere to make this fit the Q&A format of the site?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, changed it a bit.  Also working with MS/Azure support on this issue as well, so if they solve it, I will post the solution.